# Iterating two ArrayLists like in a 2-dimensional Array

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am trying to Iterate two ArrayList: One of them, called "gegner" is a list about enemys and another one called "waende" is about walls.

Whenever a wall and an Enemy touch, both should loose one durability / health.
As it didn't work at the same time, I created a new method that should remove the death Objects from the Lists.

My idea was:

```
public void removeDeathObjects() {
    Wand tempW;
    Gegner tempG;
    for (Iterator<Gegner> it = gegner.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        tempG = it.next();
        for (Iterator<Wand> it2 = waende.iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
            tempW = it2.next();

                if(tempW.isDestroyed()){
                    it2.remove();
                }
                if (tempG.isDeath()){
                    it.remove();
                }
        }   

    }
}
```

But the program throws an "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" in the Line `it.remove()` java.lang.IllegalStateException" as soon as there are at least two walls, and the enimies aren't killed completely.

Where did I failed?

If you wanted, I could give you the whole code but it's pretty long ._.

PS: sorry for bad English

Comment: I don't get why your two loops are nested. Don't you just want something like `gegner.removeIf(g -> g.isDeath())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have nested two completely independent loops. Looking at your code, it is evident that the inner loop on `waende` has nothing to do with the outer loop on `gegner`: your actions on `waende` do not depend on any check on `gegner`. What happens is that when `tempG.isDeath()` is true, `it.remove()` executes repeatedly, for every `Wand` in `waende`. The first removal on the iterator succeeds, but the second fails.

What you need to do is to separate the two loops:

```
public void removeDeathObjects() {
    Wand tempW;
    Gegner tempG;
    for (Iterator<Gegner> it = gegner.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        tempG = it.next();
        if (tempG.isDeath()){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    for (Iterator<Wand> it2 = waende.iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
        tempW = it2.next();
        if(tempW.isDestroyed()){
            it2.remove();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You've swapped the two `if` blocks. ;-) Fix this and you have my up-vote. And might as well put `tempG = it.next()` and `tempW = it2.next()` directly in the `for` loop.

Comment: @JulienLopez Bah! Thanks for pointing out my mistake! As for the changes to the `for` loops, I like to touch questions' code as little as possible, if only to make clearer what I want to say.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--

> IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method

Instead of iterating manually, you can do this in Java 8:

```
public void removeDeathObjects() {
    gegner.removeIf(g -> g.isDeath());
    waende.removeIf(w -> w.isDestroyed());
}
```